# Cannot infer groovy classpath when using gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have a trivial Gradle project:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'HelloWorld'
```

With one Groovy source file in `src/main/groovy`:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        print "hello world"
    }
}
```

I type `gradle run` and get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Cannot infer Groovy class path because no Groovy Jar was found on class path: [/Users/jzwolak/files/experimenting/gradle/groovy-project/build/classes/java/main]

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 0s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

How do I configure the Groovy classpath for Gradle?

I have Groovy at `/usr/local/opt/groovy/libexec/`

Comment: I ran into this with Gradle 7.2. My answer was to change all occurrences of `testCompile` to `testImplementation`:

 "compile and testCompile configurations are removed in Gradle 7+. You can use implementation and testImplementation instead." (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4403048541330-Could-not-find-method-testCompile-for-arguments-group-junit-name-junit-version-4-12-on-object-of-type-org-gradle-api-internal-artifacts-dsl-dependencies-DefaultDependencyHandler-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to declare a groovy dependency, as in the documentation https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/groovy_plugin.html#sec:groovy_dependency_management

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.14'
}
```

Comment: Is there a use for the Groovy plugin without this dependency? I don't understand why the plugin would not include the dependency already.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? What version of groovy would the plugin add? What if you wanted to upgrade? What if you wanted to downgrade? No, you always need to declare the version of groovy you want to use, if you use the groovy plugin

Comment: You don't have to declare java as a dependency for the Java plugin to work. The Groovy plugin could work the same way and I argue this would be more intuitive. The version of Groovy could still be switched any number of ways... including by adding an explicit dependency.

Comment: I also think the documentation could be made clearer on this. The addition of the dependency should occur close to the top of the documentation in the "Usage" section.

Comment: I have `implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.11'` in my `dependencies{}` and I still have that error. I am confused..

Comment: same problem to me..that started happening after switching from single module to multi-module project structure