# Grails "war" invocation not passing extra properties to Gradle

Tags: gradle, grails, groovy

When invoking the "grails war" command, the grails.env property is passed to Gradle, but any other property that I define with -D is not being passed.

I have verified that Gradle will get the properties and I can print them with a command like "gradle -Dgrails.env=development -Dfoo.bar=blech"

Invoking grails with this command:

grails -Dgrails.env=development -Dfoo.bar=blech war
build.gradle:

```
ext {
    currentBuildEnvironment = System.properties['grails.env']
    println "Current build environment is ${currentBuildEnvironment}"
    fooBar = System.properties['foo.bar']
    println "fooBar: ${fooBar}"
}
```

This properly prints "development" for currentBuildEnvironment, but prints null for fooBar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, you not allowed to pass custom properties to `grails` command.

From [Grails Command Line documentation](https://docs.grails.org/4.0.1/guide/commandLine.html):

> The grails command is a front to a gradle invocation, because of this
>   there can be unexpected side-effects. For example, when executing
>   grails -Dapp.foo=bar run-app the app.foo system property won’t be
>   available to your application. This is because bootRun in your
>   build.gradle configures the system properties. To make this work you
>   can simply append all System.properties to bootRun in build.gradle
>   like:
>
> ```
> bootRun{
>    systemProperties System.properties // Please note not to use '=', because this will > override all configured systemProperties. This will append them.
> }
> ```

And use in your script for fetching any custom properties:

```
ext {
    fooBar = bootRun.systemProperties['foo.bar']
    println "fooBar: ${fooBar}"
}
```

Also, you can pass a limited set of properties based on prefix:

```
bootRun{
    systemProperties System.properties.inject([:]){acc,item-> item.key.startsWith('foo.')?acc << [(item.key.substring('foo.'.length())):item.value]:acc }
}
```

And just fetch property without prefix:

```
ext {
    fooBar = bootRun.systemProperties['bar']
    println "fooBar: ${fooBar}"
}
```

You can play with passing properties in `bootRun` section:

```
systemProperties System.properties.inject([:]){acc,item-> item.key.startsWith('foo.')?acc << [(item.key):item.value]:acc }
```

will have all properties starting from 'foo' and with suffix:

```
bootRun.systemProperties['foo.bar']
```

Comment: I tried that approach, but it did not work:


> Task :compileGroovy FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.
> Cannot infer Groovy class path because no Groovy Jar was found on class path:

Comment: @tkmilbaugh if you want help, you will probably need to be very explicit about what "did not work" actually was....

Comment: @tkmilbaugh your compile error can be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120352/cannot-infer-groovy-classpath-when-using-gradle

Comment: @Andriy Budzinskyy That solved the Initial problem, but now I get:
```
> Task :compileGroovy FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.
> org/grails/io/support/Resource

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.....
```
The error does not actually describe what went wrong with org.grails.io.support.Resource, which is a standard part of Grails, I believe.

Comment: @tkmilbaugh do you see these errors when added `bootRun` section?

Comment: @AndriyBudzinskyy, when I added "systemProperties System.properties" to bootRun, that introduced the "Cannot infer Groovy class path" error. When I added "compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.17'" to the dependencies in the Gradle file, I then get the "org/grails/io/support/Resource" error.

Comment: @AndriyBudzinskyy Actually, after removing a lot of the fiddling that I have done to the build.gradle file, the suggested answer of adding "systemProperties System.properties" to the bootRun section does not change anything, I still get the original error, fooBar is null.

Comment: @tkmilbaugh I've updated my answer, double-tested in different scenarios. Hope it will help.

Comment: @AndriyBudzinskyy I wonder if it is dependent on the Grails version. I am using version 3.3.10, and I still get null, even with your updated answer.

Comment: @tkmilbaugh I used grails 4.0.1 but I see grails 3.3.10 has the same documentation for command line parameters: http://docs.grails.org/3.3.10/guide/single.html#commandLine

Comment: @AndriyBudzinskyy thanks for all of your help, everything is working well.